# confused about operators c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

here is the operator function(inSeconds is of type int)

```
const Time Time::operator +( const Time& t) const {
    return Time(inSeconds_ + t.inSeconds_);
}
```

but i need to also make this code work with this operator. (t1 being an instance of time and 12 being an integer) without swapping the values in the the order)

```
Time t(12 + t1);
```

please help me, sorry if this made no sense im a newbie.

thanks

Comment: Please don't deface your questions after they've received good answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the function a global function, not a member function.
2. Add a constructor to `Time` that takes an `int` (representing seconds) as an argument.

The following code works for me:

```
struct Time
{
   Time(int sec) : inSeconds_(sec) {}
   int inSeconds_;
};

Time operator+(Time const& lhs, Time const& rhs)
{
   return Time(lhs.inSeconds_ + rhs.inSeconds_);
}

int main()
{
   Time t1(10);
   Time t2(12 + t1);
}
```

Comment: I'd clarify that you get by doing only one of these, not necessarily both (it's not clear from your answer that you don't have to do both). To explain for OP, (2) will work because a one-arg constructor (if it's not marked `explicit`) becomes a conversion operator from the argument type to the class type, so `Time(int)` will implicitly be used to convert `int` values to `Time` objects.

Comment: @cdhowie, Making the `operator+` a member function does not work with g++ 4.7.3.

Comment: Interesting, what I should have said anyway is that you *have* to do (2) but *may not* have to do (1) (but you should anyway). (1) without (2) doesn't really solve the problem unless you add more overloads. So ignore me. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a free function operator.

```
struct Time {
  // ...
};

// note: outside the class

Time operator+(const Time& left, const int& right)
{
  return Time( /* whatever should go here */);
}
```

Always prefer to write binary operators as free functions that do their work in terms of utility methods on the class - your life will be easier.